# Getting Error Loop Variable while trying to iterate child records in parent loop

Tags: apex

Getting Error:

> Loop Variable must be a generic SObject or list of concrete SObject or List of: ProductConsumed

Description: We are trying to iterate child records in parent loop. but getting the above error. Any help would be appreciated on this. Please find my code below

```java
for(ProductConsumed prdData :row.ProductsConsumed){
    ProductConsumed prdWrap = new ProductConsumed();
    prdWrap.productDescription = String.valueOf(product2.Description) ;
    prdWrap.quantityConsumed = prdData.QuantityConsumed;
    prdWrap.unitprice = prdData.unitprice;
    prodWrap.Name = prdData.product2.Name;
    prodConsumed.add(prdWrap);
}
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. `String.valueOf(product2.Description)` is hiding a bug. You're going to end up getting the word `Description` instead of the product's description. Use `prdData.product2.Description` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class named `ProductConsumed` that is [shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm) the sObject [`ProductConsumed`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/sforce_api_objects_productconsumed.htm). Either rename the wrapper so it doesn't conflict, or change your loop variable data type to `Schema.ProductConsumed`.

```
for(Schema.ProductConsumed prdData :row.ProductsConsumed) {
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox this worked :)